# What is the primary layout if you have many layout files defined in an android app?

Tags: java, android

In an android project with many layouts how can I find what is the primary one without needing to actually run the app?  By "primary" I mean what the user sees when he starts the application in his phone. The "main" UI.

Comment: What is your definition of "the primary layout"?

Comment: @CommonsWare:What the user sees when he starts the application in his phone. The "main" UI. I am sorry for my terminology but I am newbie in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What the user sees when he starts the application in his phone

There really isn't a "primary layout", then. It may be that *your code* has a "primary layout", but that is not an Android construct, let alone a requirement.

I am going to assume that by "starts the application", you mean "taps an icon in the home screen's launcher". In that case, "what the user sees" is whatever activity that you have defined in your manifest that corresponds to that icon. It will have an `<intent-filter>` for the `MAIN` action and the `LAUNCHER` category. You may have more than one, depending upon how you set up your app.

When that activity runs, *you* decide what the UI is. That *might* be by calling `setContentView()` in the activity, in which case whatever layout you are referencing there might be construed as your "primary layout".